# Most basic way to map a raster in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 4 rasters (Formal class RasterLayers) that I brought into R (from .tif files) and stacked. I also have an sf object that I made from a spatial polygon, and am successfully mapping using ggplot2. So the data creation code looks like below:

```
# BRING IN rasters:
setwd("PATH")
rice_high <- raster("Rice/ylHr0_rice_high.tif")
rice_low <- raster("Rice/ylLr0_rice_low.tif")
wheat_high <- raster("Wheat/ylHr0_wheat_high.tif")
wheat_low <- raster("Wheat/ylLr0_wheat_low.tif")

# Crop rasterstack with shapefile, distVDS_final 
# (distVDS_final is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame holding India's 1966 districts)
GAEZstack <- stack(rice_high,rice_low,wheat_high,wheat_low)
GAEZstack <- crop(GAEZstack, distVDS_final)

# make shapefile into an sf object for ggplot2 mapping 
# (distVDS_betas is distVDS_final with district-level data merged in, for mapping) 
distVDS_betas <- st_as_sf(distVDS_betas)

# Making a state-level map by dissolving the districts within states by STNAME
states <- distVDS_betas |>
  dplyr::group_by(STNAME) |>
  dplyr::summarise()
```

I've been mapping district-level characteristics (e.g. X below) with code like this:

```
ggplot(data = distVDS_betas) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = X)) +
  scale_fill_scico(palette = "cork", name = "beta") +
  ggtitle("title") +
  geom_sf(data = states, lwd = .5, color = "#000000",fill = NA)
```

Now I want to (a) make sure the two files have the same projection, and (b) use ggplot2 to map the raster with the state shapefile over it, rather than map distVDS_betas$X with the state shapefile over it.

I don't know how to pull a crs out of an sf object, and the code i used to use to pull out of a raster object oddly isn't working. I can pull it out of the sp object before transforming, but basically wondering what is the most efficient way to make sure the 2 projections match, now that i'm using sf objects. And I have no idea how to do the ggplot2, I tried variations of the code below but nothing worked.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_raster(data = GAEZstack[[1]], aes(x = x, y = y))
```

I realize I should be able to find this online, but I see so many variations of code, and can't figure out how to apply them to my own data. I've just started working with sf objects / ggplot2.

Comment: You've `raster::stack` with default options (i.e. `quick=FALSE`), and the result without error tells you the rasters have the same resolution and extent as FALSE forces checks on these characteristics. And migrating your process to `terra` will simplify your life.

Comment: After conversion with `st_as_sf` you can handle the object with {sf}'s methods as covered in the documentation and amply discussed on gis.stackexchange.com. Note that {sf} offers `geom_sf` for use with {ggplot2}, and the latter provides `coord_sf` in turn.

Comment: for CRS manipulation there is `sf::st_crs()` function and/or `terra::crs()`. And moving the process to `terra` as mentioned by @Chris will help you. BTW, for plotting spatial objects please consider `tmap` package.

Comment: If you want to stick to ggplot2 please use `terra` instead of `raster` and check the `tidyterra` package: `ggplot() +
tidyterra::geom_spatraster(data = GAEZstack[[1]])`